# If the UIApplicationMain() never returns then when does the autorelease pool gets released?

Tags: iphone, cocoa

For code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Apple's doc clearly specifies:

> Return Value:
>   Even though an integer return type is specified, this function never returns. When users terminate an iPhone application by pressing the Home button, the application immediately exits by calling the exit system function with an argument of zero.

Secondly, in
 `int UIApplicationMain (
   int argc,
   char *argv[],
   NSString *principalClassName,
   NSString *delegateClassName
);`
how can we access the argv from our UIApplication subclass?

Comment: Why would you want to access `argv`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The autorelease pool *doesn't* get released.  Instead, the OS simply removes your application from memory.

Comment: Also, note that NSAutoreleasePools may be nested. Such nested pools are created during each event handler. Memory autoreleased in application code is mostly likely caught by one of these nested pools which are drained during the app's normal behavior.

Answer (score 3):

As for the values of `argc` and `argv` Apple documentation states the following :

> NSApplicationMain itself ignores the
>   argc and argv arguments. Instead,
>   Cocoa gets its arguments indirectly
>   via _NSGetArgv, _NSGetArgc, and
>   _NSGetEnviron (see [crt_externs.h]).g

Answer (score 1):

The main `autorelease` pool may not get released, but the `UIApplicationMain` has an event handler loop which drains it after each event.

As apple documentation states: (Under section iOS section "Allocate Memory Wisely")

> Objects released using the autorelease
>   method stay in memory until you
>   explicitly drain the current
>   autorelease pool or until the next
>   time around your event loop.